# Getting error while using @Autowired in the springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Springboot project in which I have two service interfaces whom I am injecting in my Controller

StudentService

```
public interface StudentService {

    void addStudent(Student student);
    //other functions
}
```

TeacherService

```
public interface TeacherService {

    void addStudent(Teacher teacher);
    //other functions
}
```

When I am using @Autowired for the StudentService it is working fine but I am getting an error when I am using @Autowired for the TeacherService in my Controller.I try alot but did not find the cause of the error.

My Controllers

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudenService studenService;
    ....
    ....
}
```

```
@Controller
public class TeacherController {

    @Autowired
    TeacherService teacherService;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Do you have implementations for both interfaces annoyed by @Service ?

Comment: What kind of error you get ?

Comment: There's a typo between StudentService and StudenService

Answer (score 1):

annotate the service class with @Service annotation

@Service
public interface TeacherService {

```
void addStudent(Teacher teacher);
//other functions
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Service on the ServiceImpl class and try again. I think that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The @Autowired will be used to create a link between two objectS inside the container.
it seems that you used @service or @component in the StudentService implementation and missed it in the TeacherService implementation.

Please make sure to use @component for the TeacherService implementation. so in this way the object will be created inside the container.

```
@Service or @component
public class TeacherServiceImp implements TeacherService {
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use @Component here to create bean for `TeacherServiceImpl` class. I think both will work same.

```
@Service
public class TeacherServiceImp implements TeacherService {
//your codes 
}
```

```
@Component
public class TeacherServiceImp implements TeacherService {
//your codes 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally happens when you might have not used @Service at your Service implementation or The service interface has not been implemented yet.

```
@Service
public class TeacherServiceImp implements TeacherService {
//your codes
}
```